# How can I move the Y-axis to the right?

Tags: highcharts

I am developing a graph in highcharts and I need a linear graph with the y-axis on the right, how can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
opposite: true,
```

to yAxis options

[watch this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/)